# Transitive relation on a Set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given a set $A=\{1,2,3\}$. My book says that $R=\{(1,2)\}$ is transitive but $R \cup R^{-1}$ (i.e., $R$ union $R$ inverse) is not transitive. From what I understand is, $R$ cannot be transitive because $1$ cannot map to $2$ because there is no $(1,1)$ or $(2,2)$ in $R$ needed for $1$ to map to $1$ and then $1$ to $2$, or $1$ to $2$ and then $2$ to $2$. Am I right, or am I missing something? if I can get this right then I think I can understand the "not transitive" part of the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Totally correct!!

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to put it in the language you're using: $1$ can absolutely map to $2$ (or more properly 'be related' to $2$). What transitively prohibits is a situation where $1$ maps to $2$ and $2$ maps to $c$ but $1$ does not map to $c.$ In your example relation $R = \{(1,2)\}$ there is no other relation where $2$ maps to $c$ (for some $c$), so there is nothing going on that transitivity prohibits.

However when you look at $R\cup R^{-1} = \{(1,2),(2,1)\}$ you have $1R2$ and $2R1$ so transitivity would demand $1R1.$ (And since you have $2R1$ and $1R2$ it also would demand $2R2$.) Since you don't have $1R1$, it is not transitive.

Comment: I understand the second part of the problem.  So if I'm getting this correctly, the transitivity condition can still hold for just two elements too, i.e., for just one ordered pair, like 1 is related to 2 only. In other words, the minimum condition for transitivity is aRb, provided A={a,b} and hence, there is no need for bRc ( for an arbitrary c in A). Am I correct here?

Comment: @l.b. I didn't follow what you said, so I suspect you don't quite get the definition of transitivity (or maybe it's the vacuous truth of the definition in the case here that's confusing). Transitivity means for all $a,b,c$ if $aRb$ and $bRc$ then $aRc.$ Friendship would be a transitive relation on people if a friend of a friend is always a friend. If meg and jim are the only two people in the world and meg is a friends with jim but jim is not friends with meg then there is no person who is a friend of a friend. So it's true (vacuously) that every friend of friend is a friend.

Answer (score 0):

$R$ is transitive if, whenever $(x,y)\in R $ and $(y,z)\in R$ then also $(x,z)\in R$.
Thus to show that $R$ is *not* transitive, you'd have to exhibit $x,y,z$ such that $(x,y)\in R$, $(y,z)\in R$, but $(x,z)\notin R$. Check again: You  can't do that.

Comment: yes, that's what i thought initially because how can a relation with just a single ordered pair with distinct elements be transitive? i mean, for a relation to be transitive there must be at least three elements (same or distinct) and that there is a mapping from the first to the last. so my book is wring then. right?

Comment: @l.b. Your book is right. Any relation with only one ordered pair will automatically be transitive. To fail to be transitive you would need to have$1R2$ and $2Rx$ for some $x$ but not $1Rx.$ This failure can't happen if there's no other relation $2Rx.$

Comment: can you explain to me how a relation with only one ordered pair is automatically transitive, from the perspective of (x,y)∈R and (y,z)∈R then also (x,z)∈R.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. $R\cup R^{-1} = \{(1,2),(2,1)\}$. For being transitive, the pairs $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ need to be in there.

Comment: ok, let me simplify my question: how is R here transitive?

Comment: $R$ is transitive, since the premise of the definition, $xRy \wedge yRz\Rightarrow xRz$, is not met and so the implication is true.

Comment: so how exactly can i apply the transitive definition to R={(1,2)} ? can someone explain to me how or in what way do the elements 1 and 2 in (1,2) fit within the transitive definition parameters?